# HTML datatable Export to Excel

Tags: javascript, html

We used the following code its working fine but how we set Save as Type 'Excel' in IE windows popup? Is there any possibilities to generate multiple excel sheets using different datatables as source?

```
// If Internet Explorer(Not supported Data URIs), Check navigator details & find whether it is IE or NOT    
if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE ") > 0 || !!window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
    exportIF.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    exportIF.document.write(document.getElementById('dataTable').innerHTML]);
    exportIF.document.close();
    exportIF.focus();
    //SaveAs command to Save CSV File
    sa = exportIF.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, name + ".xls");
    return (sa);  
}
else //other browsers : Chrome/FireFox (Supported Data URIs)
{
    var bb = new Blob([document.getElementById('dataTable').innerHTML], {
                type: "application / vnd.ms - excel"
            });
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            link.download = name + '.xls';;
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(bb);
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```